# draggable divs lose their "float left" property after they are dropped

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a jquery example that the draggable divs are "float left" on the start position (= refresh the google chrome). When I drag them to any droppable divs, the "float left" is gone forever.

My goal is, the draggable divs should always have "float left" on the start position. On other droppable divs they can have any float alignment, it doesn't matter.

How can I solve this problem?

```js
$(function() {
        $(".ui-widget-content").draggable({
            revertDuration : 100,
            revert : function(event, ui) {
                $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                    top : 0,
                    left : 0
                };
                return !event;
            }
        });
        $("#droppable").droppable({
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(this);
            }
        });
        $("#parent").droppable({
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(this);
            }
        });
    });

    <style>
        div .floatleft {
            float:left;
        }
        .clearBoth { 
            clear:both; 
        }

    </style>
    </head>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
  rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"> 
   </script>

   </head>

   <body>
   <div id="parent" class="ui-widget ui-state-default">
        <p>droppable foat left (start position)</p>
       <div id="origin" class="floatleft">
           <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
               <p>draggable 1</p>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div id="origin2" class="floatleft">
               <div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
                   <p>draggable 2</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <br class="clearBoth" />

   <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
        <p>other droppable</p>
   </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your CSS, remove the space between div and .floatleft (make it div.floatleft)

Comment: You have an orphaned closing `</div>` in your code that does not match any `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you drag the p-Tag away, and leave the `<div id="origin" class=floatleft></div>` over. When you pull it back you dont pull it inside of those divs and therefore they don´t get the `float: left` css applied.

My suggestion would be to change the css:

```
#parent p{
  float:left;
}
```

This should do it I think

Answer (score 0):

All your suggestions are helpful. Thanks

This seems to be the best solution for me:

```
<style>
    div.floatleft ,.ui-widget-content {
        float:left;
    }
    .clearBoth { 
        clear:both; 
    }
</style>        
   <div id="parent" class="ui-widget ui-state-default floatleft">
        <p>droppable foat left (start position)</p>
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <p>draggable 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
            <p>draggable 2</p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

```
<br class="clearBoth" />

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header floatleft">
    <p>other droppable</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to clean up your example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".ui-widget-content").draggable({
    revertDuration: 100,
    revert: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      };
      return !event;
    }
  });
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).appendTo(this);
    }
  });
  $("#parent").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).appendTo(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.clearBoth {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js">
</script>

<div id="parent" class="ui-widget ui-state-default">
  <p>droppable float left (start position)</p>
  <div id="origin-1" class="floatleft">
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>draggable 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="origin-2" class="floatleft">
    <div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>draggable 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br class="clearBoth" />

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>other droppable</p>
</div>
```

This allows clean drag and drop. There is an issue in your Droppable. Basically, you assign the same `top` and `left` for anything that is being dropped. This will cause all items to land on top of each other regardless of their float status.

It's not clear, but I think when an item is dropped to `#droppable` you want it to be a block, yet when you drop it back to `#parent` you want it to be inline-block (so that it's not a big block).

Something to remember with Draggables, they use element styles to manage the position and this will often over-ride your CSS. A handy trick is to `$(ui.droppable).attr("style", "");` which will clear out any widget added styling.

So I think the fix is to fix your `#parent` droppable. I would suggest something like:

```
$("#parent").droppable({
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable)
      .attr("style", "")
      .detach()
      .appendTo(this);
  }
});
```

This does not put the element back into one of the `origin` elements. It appends it to the `#parent`. Again, your post is not clear what you want to have happen here. So this adds the element back, it still floats left, but it's also trying to block.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".ui-widget-content").draggable({
    revertDuration: 100,
    revert: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      };
      return !event;
    }
  });
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).detach().css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).appendTo(this);
    }
  });
  $("#parent").droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable)
        .attr("style", "")
        .detach()
        .appendTo(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.clearBoth {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js">
</script>

<div id="parent" class="ui-widget ui-state-default">
  <p>droppable float left (start position)</p>
  <div id="origin-1" class="floatleft">
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>draggable 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="origin-2" class="floatleft">
    <div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>draggable 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br class="clearBoth" />

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>other droppable</p>
</div>
```

Feel free to edit your post or comment with some clarification. Hope this helps.